# Read messages in idIRC

Tags: delphi

hi i am trying to read messages from users in the IRC channel using IdIRC with Delphi XE2, the problem is that there is no "OnMessaje" event in my version of idIRC, try using "OnRaw" but the content only shows text the message and not the user name

What is the event to read the messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `OnPrivateMessage` and `OnNotice` events.  The sender of an inbound message will be in the `SenderNick` and `SenderHost` properties.